# SVG - Different stroke width on different svg items

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to apply the same stroke width to my CSS on my webpage using CSS:

```
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10pt;
  stroke: red;
}
```

However the rendering is completely different on some SVG. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kaoo1jdb/

It should be quite straightforward but it's not. I am guessing it is due to scaling effect but I don't know how to fix it.

Does anyone have any idea?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The viewboxes of the two SVG are quite different...one is 7 times the size of the other.

So....to get the same effect you must use the same multiplier for px size (at least as an interim step pending other options)

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kaoo1jdb/1/)

```
#A path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke: red;
}

#B path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 70;
  stroke: red;
}

svg {
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
}
```

You may be able to see what else might have a similar effect with a little more research.

Useful [**Article/tutorial**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html)

EDIT: A quick google gave me this property:

```
 vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;
```

Reference [**Link**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-SVG2-20140211/painting.html#NonScalingStroke)

[**JSfiddle Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/macnxgrL/1/)

```
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: red;
  vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;
}
```